# Access sending emails via SMTP

Tags: vba, ms-access, smtp

I have the following basic Send Object Macro.

```
Function McrSnapshotCallData()
On Error GoTo McrSnapshotCallData_Err

DoCmd.SendObject acQuery, "Qry_SnapShot", "Excel97-Excel2003Workbook(*.xls)", "xxx@xxx.com", "", "", "Calls", "Please find attached", False, ""


McrSnapshotCallData_Exit:
Exit Function

McrSnapshotCallData_Err:
MsgBox Error$
Resume McrSnapshotCallData_Exit

End Function
```

I need to be able to send run this macro on a server using a scheduler enabling an email to be sent out.

Currently this requires and outlook account on the server and it does not have one. Is it possible to include SMTP server details so this can be run automatically without me having to log on every night and send this.

Please can you me help adjust this if possible.

Sorry I am not very good with VBA stuff. Thanks

Comment: Is any other mail client present?

Comment: No Mail client available on that server

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend these tools:

**Blat**: http://www.blat.net/  (free)
Blat is a Windows (32 & 64 bit) command line utility that sends eMail using SMTP.

**Chilkat** ActiveX libraries: http://www.chilkatsoft.com/email-features.asp  (not free, but a lot more options)
[MailMan](https://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/xChilkatMailManRef.html): The Chilkat MailMan class is reponsible for sending email though SMTP and receiving/managing email on POP3 servers.
[Email](https://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/xChilkatEmailRef.html): Represents a complete Email object.

In both cases you'd first save the query as xls (DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet) and then mail that file.